# Js/postscribe appended script tag has suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I've been using postscribe to dynamically load a form with client date, this was working fine for months but has suddenly stopped working. There's no console errors, the script tag is added to the page as expected but it doesn't run anymore, any ideas.

```
      // Grab the values from your form and sanitize them
  var title = $("h1.product-single__title").text().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');    
  var pp = $("#SingleOptionSelector-1").val().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');
  var pc = $("#SingleOptionSelector-2").val().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');
  var pq = $("#Quantity-product-template").val().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');    
  var pcol = $(".bold_option_title").text().replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-'); 

  // Log the values to console for debugging purposes
  console.log(title, pp, pc, pq, pcol);

  // Construct the script tag with the appropriate src URL
  var formScript = '<script src="https://forms.pabbly.com/embed/rpW0-439981?Lgu1b=' + title + '&j6A5p=' + pp + '&zUNDP=' + pc + '&zuKXX=' + pq + '&eF1Oj=' + pcol + '&w=350" async><\/script>';

  // Use postscribe to write the script tag to the #visual-form element
  postscribe('#visual-form', formScript, {
    done: function() {
      console.info('Form script has been delivered.');
    }
  });
```